# I am encountering the error " Invalid number of parameters". how can i solve it

Tags: command-line

C:\Users\DR GLADMAN GEE>Xcopy C:\Users\DR GLADMAN GEE\Documents\CCTSkills C:\Users\DR GLADMAN GEE\Desktop/E

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, when your file or folder name has spaces in it, you must enclose it in quotation marks.

```
C:\Users\DR GLADMAN GEE>XCOPY "C:\Users\DR GLADMAN GEE\Documents\CCTSkills" "C:\Users\DR GLADMAN GEE\Desktop" /E
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotation marks ("") to group filenames *containing spaces* into a single parameter. You probably mean

`xcopy "C:\Users\DR GLADMAN GEE\Documents\CCTSkills" "C:\Users\DR GLADMAN GEE\Desktop" /E`

which leaves only three (3) parameters: source, destination and an extra flag ("/e").